# Logarithmic scale in the legend of a ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

Is there a way to use a logarithmic scale in the colour legend of a `ListContourPlot`? The contours can be logged by taking the `Log10` of the data, but this doesn't transfer to the legend. As an example, with the code:

```
test = Flatten[Table[{i, j, Log10[RandomReal[{0, 1*^10}]]}, {j, 1, 100}, {i, 1, 100}], 1];

ListContourPlot[test, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I get equally spaced contours for values <7, 8, 9 and 10. Could I plot these data with equally spaced contours corresponding to values 0.1, 1 and 10?

---

Another example, where you'd expect to see logarithmic data:

```
test = Flatten[Table[{i, j, Log10@Exp[-(i + j)^2]}, {j, 1, 10}, {i, 1, 10}], 1];
ListContourPlot[test, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One way is to segment the data into as many sections as you want color resolution, 1) order set 2) divide into k equaly large parts 3) make a function that returns which division a value would lie in divided by number of divisions 4) scale `ColorFunction`s argument with that manually, I tried implementing this but [got stuck](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16487/break-inside-colorfunction) here's [how far I got](http://pastie.org/5544048)

Comment: I wonder if the [CustomTicks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package can be used here.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, but I guess you could still pass the divisions to `Contours`

Comment: Do you get something close to what you need playing with the parameters in `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}},  Function[{min, max}, Rescale[{.1, 1, 5, 10}, {0, 10}, {min, max}]]]`?

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable help! Unfortunately I was not yet able to solve my problem. Using kguler's suggestion, the tick values in the legend are displayed as I would want them, but the colour gradation stays the same - not logarithmic as I would like. To make myself clear, the jump in colour from 0.1 to 1 is smaller than the jump from 1 to 10, and so on. Any further suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think I found a way to solve the problem.

Using a different example:

```
test = Flatten[Table[{i, j, Exp[RandomReal[{0, 10}]]}, {j, 1, 100}, {i, 1, 100}], 1];

min = Log[10, Min[test[[;; , 3]]]];
max = Log[10, Max[test[[;; , 3]]]];

ListContourPlot[test,
InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
Contours -> Flatten[Table[{1., 2., 5.}*10^n, {n, 1, 4}]], 
ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, ColorData["Rainbow"][(Log[10, f] - min)/(max - min)]],
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All], 
PlotRange -> All]
```

The result is

[image]

Thank you all for your input!