# Break[] inside ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, version-8, version-9

**Bug introduced in `V8.0` or earlier and persisting through `V12.1.0` or later. Fixed in `V13.0.0` or earlier**

---

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:= (Do[Break[],{i,1,2}];x)
Plot[x,{x,0,1},ColorFunction->(ColorData["Rainbow"][f[#]]&)]
```

> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[].

What's going on here? I've tried setting `HoldFirst` attribute on `f` and I've also tried using `Unevaluated` which gives surprising results:

```
(* Works fine, gives plot colored as expected *)
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Unevaluated[ColorData["Rainbow"][f[#1]]] &)]

(* Gives a black and white plot with error:
   "Unevaluated is not a Graphics primitive or directive" *)
ListContourPlot[IdentityMatrix[3],
  ColorFunction->(Unevaluated[ColorData["Rainbow"][f[#1]]]&)]
```

**Edit** This on the other hand works:

```
Plot[x,{x,0,1},ColorFunction->Function[c,ColorData["Rainbow"][f[c]]]]
```

Which only difference is that it uses `Function[c,ColorData["Rainbow"][f[c]]]]` instead of `Function[ColorData["Rainbow"][f[Slot[1]]]]]`

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi if you don't like getting into the internals I think you chose the wrong question. I think this behaviour is quiiite weird

Comment: I have no idea what's going on. It seems like `Return` and `Break` just don't work properly when running a `ColorFunction`. The `Unevaluated` might fix it because the `ColorFunction` doesn't actually evaluate the `Break` statement while inside the function

Comment: Perhaps, `ColorFunction` does some checking on the structure of the option (see that it can receive a string, a number, a function, and treat those cases differently). And, for some reason, when it's a function, Break and Return die. However, not when it's a function in the form `Function[Null, ...]`. Nonsense

Comment: Another interesting observation is that `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Composition[ColorData["Rainbow"], f]]` does not give an error, but it does not colour the plot either.  The simpler `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Composition[ColorData["Rainbow"], # &]]` doesn't work either.  However, if I wrap it like this, `Composition[ColorData["Rainbow"], # &]`, then use `ColorFunction -> z`, it does work.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Yes, but also [After a Break the value Null is returned from the enclosing control structure.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Break.html) and `Do[Break[],{1}]===Null` is `True` :)

Comment: @Szabolcs Can you clarify how you wrap it when it works? Edit: I presume you mean `Function[z,...]`, at least that works too

Comment: This also has to do with the anonymous functions, since `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1},  ColorFunction -> (Function[c, ColorData["Rainbow"][f[c]]])]` works fine. Perhaps, @Rojo is right, and it tries some destructuring of the function and isn't careful enough about it.

Comment: @ssch Like this: `z[x_] := Composition[ColorData["Rainbow"], # &][x]`.  It failed to paste properly. There's an annoying copy/paste problem on Mac I just can't get used to ... I always end up not copying the expression I want!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this behavior is a consequence of a bad interaction of `Break` with `AbortProtect`, which in turn is probably used in some `Plot` code. It's an area that is receiving some attention in recent development work. I'm not sure what is the prognosis though.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in `V13.0.0`

```
$Version
```

> ```
> 13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)
> ```

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Do[Break[], {i, 1, 2}]; x)
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][f[#]] &)]
```

> [image: plotbug]

---

> [image: screenshot]