# Unexpected errors using NSolve in ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages, plot-themes

I ran into some weird errors when using `NSolve` inside `ColorFunction`.  Took some hours to distill the problem into a minimal example:

```
Plot[-x, {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[n1 /. NSolve[{
  0 == n1 (1 - #1^2 - n1 - E^(-2 (#1 - #2)^2) n2),
  0 == (1 - #2^2 - E^(-2 (-#1 + #2)^2) n1 - n2) n2}, {n1, n2}][[1]]] &)]
```

> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[]. (X3)
>
> Continue::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Continue[].
>
> Goto::nolabel: Label System``NSolveDump` raiseprecision not found. (etc.)

```
Hold[Break[], Break[], Break[], Continue[],
  Goto[System`NSolveDump`raiseprecision], Continue[], Break[], Continue[]]
```

Seems related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16487/break-inside-colorfunction), but potentially more confusing since no `Break` is apparently involved.

I'm using Mathematica v11.2 on MacOS 10.13.3.

Comment: Looks like a bug, though.  Probably the same one, but one can't say for sure without seeing the internals.

Comment: Since this was identified as a bug in 2012 and is still not fixed, I am tagging this question with [tag:bugs].

Comment: Thanks, I'll report it to WRI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution proposed in [the same previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16487/break-inside-colorfunction) works here: wrap the `ColorFunction` in an `Unevaluated`.

```
Plot[-x, {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Unevaluated[Hue[n1 /. NSolve[{
  0 == n1 (1 - #1^2 - n1 - E^(-2 (#1 - #2)^2) n2),
  0 == (1 - #2^2 - E^(-2 (-#1 + #2)^2) n1 - n2) n2}, {n1, n2}][[1]]]] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]